# selenium phantomjs thead there but tbody missing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

While scraping this page:

https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-(HSI)/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI

in google chrome key F12, I see the xpath

```
  t//*[@id="equity_future"]
```

has a thead and a tbody. The tbody is available.

However, inside python3 debugger, with

```
wdriver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
wdriver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(wdriver.page_source,"lxml")
```

I do see the **thead** children but the **tbody** appears empty

```
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using only [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) if you extract the **`page_source`** you can find all the **`<tbody>`** tags as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\phantomjs.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-(HSI)/Hang-Seng-Index-Futures?sc_lang=en#&product=HSI")
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output Snippet 1:

  ```
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td class="ls">Last Traded</td>
      <td class="vo">Volume</td>
      <td class="oi">Prev.Day Open Interest</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  ```
- Console Output Snippet 2:

  ```
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td class="se">Prev.Day Settlement Price</td>
      <td class="vo">Volume</td>
      <td class="oi">Prev.Day Open Interest</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  ```

Comment: Printing just driver.page_source still doesn't show tbody rows like May-19. 
Also empty 
<tbody>\n                                            </tbody>\n

Comment: @MMM Which `tbody` rows do you want to see exactly?

Comment: Here is an example row I see with Chrome


<tr class="datarow"><td>May-19</td><td>29,863</td><td class="upval">+205</td><td>29,863</td><td><span>29,862</span><br><span>29,879</span></td><td>29,554</td><td><span>29,875</span><br><span>29,412</span></td><td>147,228</td><td>121,569</td></tr>

Comment: DebanjanB  They are rows which have numbers in them. I can see them with the browser but not with PhantomJS. Do you agree?